# The subspace of complex sequences $V_{\sigma}$ is closed under what topology?

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

Let $C^\mathbb{N}$ be the vector space of complex sequences.  Let $V_{\sigma}$ be the vector subspace of $C^\mathbb{N}$ such that $(a_i) \in V_{\sigma}$ iff $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{\sigma(i)} \text{ converges }$.   If I want to show that any converging limits of sequences in $V_{\sigma}$ are contained in $V_{\sigma}$, i.e. it's closed, what topology would I need to work with?  $\sigma$ is a permutation of the indices.

Comment: For a complex sequence, what would $\sum a_{\sigma(i)} < \infty$ mean?

Comment: It would mean it converges to something in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: That's not a good denotation. Write "iff $\sum a_{\sigma(i)}$ converges".

Comment: Okay, edited that in.  What next ? :)

Answer (score 1):

We should probably use the sup norm: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#Definition)

I want to show that $V_{\sigma}$ is closed under the topology generated by the sup norm.

Let $(a_i^n)$ be a sequence of sequences in $V_{\sigma}$, i.e. $(a_i^1), (a_i^2), \dots$

Suppose it converges to a limit $(b_i) \in C^{\mathbb{N}}$, under the sup norm.  I want to show that $(b_i)$ is actually in $V_{\sigma}$.

For all $\epsilon \gt 0$ there's $N$ such that for all $n \gt N$, $\sup_{i\geq 1} |a^n_i - b_i| = \sup_{i\geq 1} |a_{\sigma(i)}^n - b_{\sigma(i)}| \lt \epsilon$ is given.

Maybe if a sequence of summable sequences converges to a sequence, then that sequence is also summable.